# Linux mint mate compiz

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Какой командой можно запустить редактор compiz чтобы можно было настроить эффекты?Пробовал вводить просто compiz и в консоле выводится вот это[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: `ccsm` наверное?

Answer (score 2):

поищем в списке пакетов упоминание слов `compiz` и `config`:

```
$ apt-cache search compiz config | sort
compiz-boxmenu - Compiz Reloaded - daemon and clients providing pop-up menus
compizconfig-settings-manager - Compizconfig Settings Manager
libcompizconfig0 - Configuration settings library for compiz
libcompizconfig0-dev - Configuration settings library for compiz - development files
python3-compizconfig - Compizconfig bindings for python3
python-compizconfig - Compizconfig bindings for python
simple-ccsm - Simple Compizconfig settings manager
```

отбрасываем какого-то демона, две библиотеки, два пакета с привязками для python. остаются: `compizconfig-settings-manager` и `simple-ccsm`.

есть ли в них что-нибудь, предназначенное для запуска пользователем? есть и там и там:

```
$ apt-file list compizconfig-settings-manager | grep bin
compizconfig-settings-manager: /usr/bin/ccsm
$ apt-file list simple-ccsm | grep bin
simple-ccsm: /usr/bin/simple-ccsm
```

ну а дальше сами выбирайте, какой из пакетов (и, соответственно, какая из программ — `ccsm` или `simple-ccsm`) вам нужен, посмотрев на их описание:

```
$ apt-cache show compizconfig-settings-manager
...
$ apt-cache show simple-ccsm
...
```

---

p.s. списки пакетов и входящих в них файлов могут, конечно, отличаться: в зависимости от дистрибутива, его версии, подключенных репозиториев.